# Use of 'use utf8;' gives me 'Wide character in print'

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8

If I run the following Perl program:

```
perl -e 'use utf8; print "鸡\n";'
```

I get this warning:

```
Wide character in print at -e line 1.
```

If I run this Perl program:

```
perl -e 'print "鸡\n";'
```

I do not get a warning.

I thought `use utf8` was required to use UTF-8 characters in a Perl script.  Why does this not work and how can I fix it? I'm using Perl 5.16.2. I have the same issue if this is in a file instead of being a one liner on the command line.

Comment: "Why does this not work?" It *does* work, but it's been my experience with Unicode that there are a lot of very broken programs out there that *look* like they're working. When you fix one thing, making the code slightly less wrong, the results seem a lot worse. It's only when you fix the *last* part that everything looks good again.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Without `use utf8` Perl interprets your string as a sequence of single byte characters. There are four bytes in your string as you can see from this:

```
$ perl -E 'say join ":", map { ord } split //, "鸡\n";'
233:184:161:10
```

The first three bytes make up your character, the last one is the line-feed.

The call to `print` sends these four characters to STDOUT. Your console then works out how to display these characters. If your console is set to use UTF8, then it will interpret those three bytes as your single character and that is what is displayed.

If we add in the `utf8` module, things are different. In this case, Perl interprets your string as just two characters.

```
$ perl -Mutf8 -E 'say join ":", map { ord } split //, "鸡\n";'
40481:10
```

By default, Perl's IO layer assumes that it is working with single-byte characters. So when you try to print a multi-byte character, Perl thinks that something is wrong and gives you a warning. As ever, you can get more explanation for this error by including `use diagnostics`. It will say this:

> (S utf8) Perl met a wide character (>255) when it wasn't expecting
>   one.  This warning is by default on for I/O (like print).  The easiest
>   way to quiet this warning is simply to add the :utf8 layer to the
>   output, e.g. binmode STDOUT, ':utf8'.  Another way to turn off the
>   warning is to add no warnings 'utf8'; but that is often closer to
>   cheating.  In general, you are supposed to explicitly mark the
>   filehandle with an encoding, see open and perlfunc/binmode.

As others have pointed out you need to tell Perl to accept multi-byte output. There are many ways to do this (see the [Perl Unicode Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html) for some examples). One of the simplest ways is to use the `-CS` command line flag - which tells the three standard filehandles (STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR) to deal with UTF8.

```
$ perl -Mutf8 -e 'print "鸡\n";'
Wide character in print at -e line 1.
鸡
```

vs

```
$ perl -Mutf8 -CS -e 'print "鸡\n";'
鸡
```

Unicode is a big and complex area. As you've seen, many simple programs appear to do the right thing, but for the wrong reasons. When you start to fix part of the program, things will often get worse until you've fixed *all* of the program.

Comment: How to spell `-Mutf8` if not in one liner perl?

Comment: @LeiYang: `use utf8;`

Answer (score 84):

All `use utf8;` does is tell Perl the source code is encoded using UTF-8. You need to tell Perl how to encode your text:

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well for programs stored in files, as opposed to one-liners on the command line, which @DaveCross's answer covers.

Answer (score 19):

Encode all standard output as UTF-8:

```
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
```

Comment: `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';` as proposed by another answer does this for STDOUT but also marks STDERR, and STDIN as UTF-8, so you get three for the price of one statement.   See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42194059

Comment: Agree. This is even better.

Comment: I can't get this simple program to correctly print curly quotes on a Windows 10 PC running Perl 5.32 .  Is something missing or is it just another thing Windows can't do right?

`BEGIN {binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";}
print "\x{201C}in curly quotes\x{201D}\n";`

Answer (score 14):

You can get close to "just do utf8 everywhere" by using the CPAN module [`utf8::all`](http://metacpan.org/module/utf8::all).

```
perl -Mutf8::all -e 'print "鸡\n";'
```

When `print` receives something that it can't print (character larger than 255 when no `:encoding` layer is provided), it assumes you meant to encode it using UTF-8. It does so, after warning about the problem.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this,

```
perl -CS filename.
```

It will also terminates that error.

Reference (abridged):

```
            The -C flag controls some of the Perl Unicode features.

            As of 5.8.1, the -C can be followed either by a number or a list of option letters.  The letters, their numeric values,
            and effects are as follows; listing the letters is equal to summing the numbers.

                I     1   STDIN is assumed to be in UTF-8
                O     2   STDOUT will be in UTF-8
                E     4   STDERR will be in UTF-8
                S     7   I + O + E
```

Comment: If you're not just running Oneliner, see here: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicook#%E2%84%9E-15:-Declare-STD%7BIN,OUT,ERR%7D-to-be-utf8

Comment: Unlike other solutions, this one doesn't require libraries to be detected

Answer (score -1):

In Spanish you can find this error when beside of begin using:

```
use utf8;
```

Your editor encoding is in a different encoding. So what you see on the editor is not what Perl does. To solve that error just change the editor encoding to **Unicode/UTF-8**.

Comment: No. This isn't what was causing the error. The code was all properly encoded as UTF8 but the output filehandle didn't know that it was.