# How to read text file contents without loss of characters in perl

Tags: perl, text, file-io, unicode, utf-8

I have the following text in text file (.txt):

> Feste begründen die Identität einer Gemeinschaft und ihr
>   Selbstverständnis nach innen. Eng damit verbunden sind Emotionen, die
>   zunächst im Zusammenhang mit einer gefühlten Zugehörigkeit zu einer
>   Fest-Gemeinschaft zu verstehen sind. Mit jedem Fest verbindet sich
>   aber auch eine emotionale Überschreitung des Alltags: Der bestimmende
>   festliche Eindruck **–** die feierliche Gestimmtheit **–** ist der einer
>   erhöhten Bedeutungshaftigkeit des Lebens, durch die sich das Festliche
>   aus dem Lauf des Alltagslebens hervorhebt und dessen Wirkmächtigkeit
>   zuvörderst anhand der Analyse des bürgerlichen Geburtstages sinnfällig
>   demonstriert werden soll.

when I read this text from .txt file, I am getting the text as shown below :

> Feste begründen die Identität einer Gemeinschaft und ihr
>   Selbstverständnis nach innen. Eng damit verbunden sind Emotionen, die
>   zunächst im Zusammenhang mit einer gefühlten Zugehörigkeit zu einer
>   Fest-Gemeinschaft zu verstehen sind. Mit jedem Fest verbindet sich
>   aber auch eine emotionale Überschreitung des Alltags: Der bestimmende
>   festliche Eindruck  die feierliche Gestimmtheit  ist der einer
>   erhöhten Bedeutungshaftigkeit des Lebens, durch die sich das Festliche
>   aus dem Lauf des Alltagslebens hervorhebt und dessen Wirkmächtigkeit
>   zuvörderst anhand der Analyse des bürgerlichen Geburtstages sinnfällig
>   demonstriert werden soll.

You can see the en-dash not present in the above text, But I want the exact text as in the (.txt) file, I also used UTF-8 but still getting without en-dash.

I am looking for your ideas to solve this in Perl.

Comment: Not enough information for a meaningful answer. What is the encoding of your input file? How are your reading data from the input file? How are you decoding the data you read from your input file. What encoding do you want in your output file? How are you writing data to your output file? How are your encoding the data you write to your output file. Basically, we need to see far more of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to begin your script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -CS

use open IO => ':utf8';
```

and then open, read, and output normally, that pragma will instruct Perl to use UTF8 encoding for all input and output, and option `-CS` will turn on Unicode support for `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR`.

You need to run your script in one of the following ways:

1. add execute permission to it, and use `./script.pl` to run it, or
2. use `perl -CS /path/to/script.pl`

Reference:
[perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)
[use utf8 gives me 'Wide character in print'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210532/use-utf8-gives-me-wide-character-in-print)

---

This script should be able to create an exact copy (checked with `diff`) of [this file](https://mega.co.nz/#!3k4SASIB!x2ZSd62-HowlfCiJjSxg_uqweR2OC6xMmjsoVdtFqvo). When it is running, the value of `${^UNICODE}` should be 7, it will print the value of this variable to `STDERR`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -CS

use strict;
use warnings;

use open IO => ':utf8';

use feature qw(switch say);

print STDERR "\${^UNICODE} = ${^UNICODE}\n";

use Data::Dumper;

open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "Cannot open $ARGV[0]: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    print;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Lee, I used the above line but I still getting the same output as without en-dash, i tried also #binmode STDOUT, ":utf8"; but not worked! but thanks for your reply, pls comment if you have any other idea

Comment: @user3354853 Please make sure your input file is using UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Sure Mr.Lee will comment you back after i tried this thanks a lot

Comment: Mr.Lee I tried using input file as UTF8 but still same error !

Comment: "that pragma will instruct Perl to use UTF8 encoding for all input and output" - actually no, that pragma will only affect output. To affect both input and output, you need `use open IO => ':utf8'`. But that assumes that the input and output are both UTF-8. We don't know that from the question.

Comment: @user3354853 I copy and paste your first text to a plain text file (created by Vim 7.3) using UTF8 encoding, after using that `open` pragma, `open` that file, read it line by line, then `print` it, then I get a exact copy of the original copy of the input file. (Perl 5.14.2) Could you offer a download link of your input file so we can test our answers with it?

Comment: @user3354853 Please recheck my updated answer, there is a mistake in the previous version.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Lee I also uploaded my txt file in the following link take a look at this :

https://mega.co.nz/#!3k4SASIB!x2ZSd62-HowlfCiJjSxg_uqweR2OC6xMmjsoVdtFqvo

Comment: @user3354853 Looks like only using `open` pragma is not enough, you also need to add `-CS` option to perl interpreter. Please check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that Perl handles your umlauts but not your dashes suggests that the file uses `windows-1252` encoding. Perl is probably assuming that the file is in `latin-1` (ISO-8859-1), an encoding that doesn't use codepoints between `80` and `9F`. The N dash being `97` in `windows-1252` would explain why Perl doesn't process it.

Try telling Perl to use `windows-1252` both for files and for the terminal, with [the open pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html):

```
use open qw( :encoding(windows-1252) :std );
```