# Remove micro sign unicode character

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

I'm trying to strip the micro (μ) unicode character from a string using perl regexs. Take the string

```
$string = "This is a micro μ and some more μμμ";
```

Using a brute force approach to remove all 'more specialised' unicode characters does the job, i.e.,

```
$string =~ s/[\x80-\xFF]+//g;
```

But the following that singles out the micro character does not work for me

```
$string =~ s/\xB5+//g;
```

Pretty sure 00B5 is the unicode for the micro sign. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is your string properly recognised as Unicode by Perl? For example, what is `length("µ")`? It should be 1; if it's more than 1, then you should look at the [Encode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode) module to decode your UTF-8 byte string into a character string. Also be aware that the micro symbol (U+00B5) and the Greek small letter mu (U+03BC) look very similar, but are considered different characters.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's the greek letter and not the micro sign - d'oh!

Comment: Please provide the output of `printf("U+%v04X\n", $string);` or `use Data::Dumper; local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($string));`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the micro sign, check out the similar Greek small letter mu, as [tobyink has suggested in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570643/regex-remove-micro-sign-unicode-character#comment38060697_24570643).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
my $string = "This is a micro μ and some more μμμ";
$string =~ s/\x{03BC}//g;
print $string;
```

Output: `This is a micro  and some more`

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/wEXG2B)

References:

- [Unicode Character 'GREEK SMALL LETTER MU' (U+03BC)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03BC/index.htm)
- [Unicode Character 'MICRO SIGN' (U+00B5)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00B5/index.htm)

Comment: Great, works. Correct, think it is the greek letter. However, when I print the string using package `utf8` I get a warning `Wide character in print at ...`. I presume this is just me getting muddled with encodings. N.B. the strings are being read in from xml.

Comment: Check this: [use utf8 gives me 'Wide character in print'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210532/use-utf8-gives-me-wide-character-in-print)