# Error:Wide character in print at X at line 35, <$fh> ?(read text files from command line)

Tags: perl

i am newbie to perl. and this is my second assignment i should create program to parse n files and print m sentences using n-grams model. long story short, i wrote this script that will take n arguments, where the first and second arguments are numeric but the rest are files names, however i am getting this error **Wide character in print at ngram.pl line 35,  line 1.**

steps to reproduce it :

input from command line : perl ngram.pl 5 10 tale-cities.txt bleak-house.txt papers.txt 
output : **Wide character in print at ngram.pl line 35,  line 1.**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
use utf8;
use Encode;
#Charles Dickens


sub checkIfNumberic
{
 my ($inp)=@_;
    if  (looks_like_number($inp)){
       return "True";
    }
    else{
        return "False" ;
    }
}
sub main
{
    my $correctInput=", your input must be something like this 5 10 somefile.txt somefile2.txt ";
    my @inputs= @ARGV;
    if (checkIfNumberic($inputs[0]) eq "False"){
        die "first argument must be numberic $correctInput\n";
    }
    if (checkIfNumberic($inputs[1]) eq "False"){
        die "second argument must be numberic $correctInput\n";
    }
    for (my $i=2;  $i< scalar @inputs ;$i++)
    {
        if (open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $inputs[$i])) {
            while (my $line = <$fh>) {
                chomp $line;
                print "$line \n";
            }
        }
    }
}

main();
```

Comment: Tip: Use `my ($min, $max, @files) = @ARGV;`

Comment: Tip: Don't return `True` and `False` (which are both true), return something true (usually `1`) and something false (usually `0`), then do `if (checkIfNumberic($min)){ ... }`, or just `if (looks_like_number($min)){ ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You decoded your inputs (the script, with `use utf8;`; and the file, with `:encoding(UTF-8)`), but you didn't encode your outputs. Add

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

This is equivalent to

```
BEGIN {
   binmode STDIN,  ':encoding(UTF-8)';
   binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
   binmode STDERR, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
}
```

It also sets the default encoding for file handles opened in its lexical scope, you can remove the existing `:encoding(UTF-8)` if you want.

Comment: thanks for your answer i just have another question . do you know any good modules to parse huge text files and tokenize strings to kind 2D array or virtual table

Comment: Highly unclear question. Post a Question, but with far more details. (Specifically, what do you mean by "kind 2d array" and "virtual table"?)