# Is it possible to make Content Export use UTF-8 instead of ANSI in perl

Tags: windows, perl, unicode, utf-8

I have created a Pl file for writing the content in txt file in perl, But when we open the file in Ubuntu system it shows the content in UTF8 and in windows system the content is shown in ANSI format and the text is  broken in txt file.

I want to make the file UTF8 default open in Windows system, so that the characters should not be broken.

Below is the my code

```
my $filename = "123.txt";
my $content = "ब लोगों के लिए एक समा sum";
open FILE, ">", $filename;
print FILE $content;
close FILE;
exit;
```

Comment: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627661/how-can-i-output-utf-8-from-perl)

Answer (score 0):

See also [Encode all standard output as utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21839448/2789312) and [Perl Unicode Cookbook: The Standard Preamble](https://www.perl.com/pub/2012/04/perlunicook-standard-preamble.html)

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my $filename = "123.txt";
my $content = "ब लोगों के लिए एक समा sum";
open(my $FILE, ">", $filename)
   or die("can't open \"$filename\": $!\n");

print $FILE $content;
```

Comment: Still on windows system in notepad++ it is opening in ANSI format, when we            manually make the file UTF8 from options than only the content is visible in original format

Comment: It's a pity, I haven't windows to test it

Comment: @sumit Which version of Windows are you using? This works perfectly well on Windows 10 for me.

Comment: I am using Windows 7

Comment: This code works perfectly fine on Windows or otherwise, as long as the source code is encoded using UTF-8.

Comment: Re "*when we manually make the file UTF8 from options than only the content is visible in original format*", I'm don't know what you mean by "original format", but if you're saying you see `ब लोगों के लिए एक समा sum` when you tell Notepad++ the file is UTF-8, then the program worked.